# ¿Cómo evito que se bloque el widget entry de tkinter mientras se ejecuta el gráfico?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, interfaz-gráfica

He estado desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en tkinter, esta aplicación requiere un grafico en tiempo real extrayendo unicamente el dato de tiempo una sola vez y continuamente el dato de recuperación en el infinito, usé time para darle un tiempo de 5 segundos al usuario para cambiarlo sin embargo no parece ser la mejor opción, lo que quiero es que no se congele el entry de recuperación en el infinito para que el usuario pueda cambiar el dato en cualquier momento, de antemano gracias.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from tkinter import *
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

Balance=Tk()
Balance.title('Balance de materia')
Balance.config(bg='grey')
Balance.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frmx=Frame(Balance, bg='grey', width=900, height=900)
frmx.pack(side='left')

datos6=StringVar()
variableTM=StringVar()

etiquetaz=Label(frmx, text='Tiempo de residencia (min)', font=('arial',12 ), fg='blue', bg='grey').place(x=30, y=190)
TiempoM=Entry(frmx, textvariable=variableTM)
TiempoM.place(x=30, y=220)


def calculos():

    TM=float(TiempoM.get())
    

    Ti=float(TiempoR.get())
    
    fig, ax= plt.subplots()
    xdata, ydata = [], []
    ln, = plt.plot([], [])

    def init():
        ax.set_xlim(0, TM)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        return ln,

    def update(frame):
        time.sleep(5)
        xdata.append(frame)
        Ti=TiempoR.get()
        if Ti=='':
            r=int(frame)
            Ti=ydata[r-1]
        Ti=float(Ti)
        #sleep 2-segundos permite modificar celdas
        ydata.append(Ti)
        ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
        return ln,


    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, TM, 50),init_func=init)
            
    embebido=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frmx)
    embebido.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=10)
    embebido.draw()

        
mostarResultados=Button(frmx, text='Mostrar comparación', cursor='hand2', command=calculos).place(x=30, y=330)
etiquetatr=Label(frmx, text='Recuperación en el infinito', font=('arial',12 ), fg='blue', bg='grey').place(x=30, y=50)
TiempoR=Entry(frmx, textvariable=datos6)
TiempoR.place(x=30, y=80)

Balance.mainloop()
```

Necesito ayuda para lograr esto así será más completo.

Comment: Y si quitas el time.sleep(5)?

Comment: No daría tiempo de que el ususario introduzca un nuevo valor y la función seguiría.

Comment: O sea, tu plan es que la función update se pause hasta que el usuario ingrese un nuevo valor? No sería mejor colocar un botón que diga "agregar al grafico" en lugar de arriesgarse a que el usuario no termine de escribir por algún motivo pasados los 5 segundos y que ingrese un valor no deseado al grafico?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que pueda ir cambiando los valores de manera automática sin necesidad de dar click en algún botón, lo de borrar el slep es evidente que lo voy a hacer para que sea más rápido el proceso, pero por ahora no encuentro otra opción, tal vez con concurrencia pero no me queda claro como podría hacerlo.